# Space war story from 1960s song "The Minstrel Boy to the War Has Gone"

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

A short story or novelette read in a 1960s science fiction magazine, probably If, Tomorrow, or Galaxy.

Much of the galaxy has been colonized by humans.  Parasitic aliens from another galaxy that control human bodies have invaded and there is a big interstellar space war with them.

After a space battle an uncontrolled man from the human side and a human girl from the invading side find each other in the wreckage and cooperate to survive, though the man fears the girl might be controlled by one of the aliens.  The girl comes from a planet famed for its sexy women before the aliens took it over.

The song "The Minstrel Boy to the War Has Gone" is part of the story and/or the title.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

["To the War is Gone"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?54567) (1966) by Richard C Meredith.

One of the aliens (or possibly a human already controlled by one) tries to persuade the hero that it's really not so bad. But he doesn't buy it and dies in a suicidal attack rather than be captured. IIRC his ship was called "Rakewind". Very reminiscent of Heinlein's "The Puppet Masters".

Comment: I see that was in the November, 1966 issue of Worlds of Tomorrow - http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?54567

Comment: FYI -- available to read online courtesy of archive.org at https://archive.org/details/Worlds_of_Tomorrow_v04n02_1966-11/page/n77